# Connecting tablet to VGA projector

Tags: settings, connection-issues, hdmi

Is it possible to connect an Android tablet to a VGA projector to make presentations of what's on its screen – and if so, how can this be done?

TL;DR:

I am searching the market for purchasing an Android tablet. The only feature that I want it to have is being able to be connected to VGA projectors for making presentations concerning my Android applications. So before buying any device, I need to know if this is possible (not looking for "device recommendations" explicitly here, but for the technical possibility).

I've searched similar question but I didn't find a definitive answer. I know I must also buy a converter but I've found out that is more difficult than it sounds. So I would like to hear some suggestions, better yet if you have achieved such a connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Some devices even have an official (branded) adaptor for doing this, such as the Asus Transformer TF-101. As you surmise, though, if the tablet doesn't support it, external convertors are quite unwieldy and typically need their own power supply, as they typically have to buffer a whole frame at a time in order to work.

Newer data projectors support HDMI or even MHL input, which allows you to use any tablet or phone with micro-HDMI or MHL output, with the appropriate cable.

Using either method, the presentations don't have to be of what is on your screen. Android 4.1 and up provide a way for apps to send different visuals to the external display from the built-in screen, so (for example) presentation apps can show your slide on the big screen and notes and controls on the tablet itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply go for a tablet that comes with a mini HDMI port then buy a HDMI TO VGA cable or converter to connect the tablet to your projector. you can follow the link here to get a list of six tablets that comes with an integrated HDMI port:
cnet.com/news/top-tablets-with-hdmi-connections

hope this helps, and that if its coming too late you already found a better solution.

Comment: The tablets listed in the article you linked to are very, VERY old (most if not all are older than this question itself)... Consider finding an up-to-date list.